# ModelBuilder - Automatize names output files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm making a ModelBuilder to facilitate some geographical treatments which concern many CSV files in a same workspace.

For that, I made an iteration on that workspace, it works but I have a problem with the output files' names.

The csv files which are input looks like that : "456789_V1_58412_FTMP_68513_PMSKD.CSV" or "123456_V2_58412_FTMP_68513_PMSKD.CSV" .

For the output names, I need the 9th first characters of the originals CSV files with "Points_" at the beginning. To resume, I need the output names looks like that : "\Défault.gdb\Points_456789_V1" or "\Défault.gdb\Points_123456_V2".

I have made some tests by writing "Points_%Name%" in the output names in my Model builder but the results are not good. I have that :"\Défault.gdb\Points_456789_V1_58412_FTMP_68513_PMSKD" .

I have 2 problems with this : 
 1 - It doesn't match with what I want to have as a result name
 2 - The name is too long for a geodatabase so my names results are heterogeneous

Please, do you have some ideas to help me?

Comment: Another issue to consider is that geodatabase cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I forgot to say that the beginning of my output names start with "Points_" or "Line_". 

And when I make this : "Points_%Name%" the names are too long .

I need that as a final result : "Points_456789_V1". I don't need the rest of the name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Calculate Value model tool. Add one just after your iterator and type in `"_".join (%Name%.split ("_")[:2])`. Then use `Points_%Value%`, assuming Calculate Values' output is **Value**. Don't forget to precondition Value to your create table tool.